# output sas data to xpt file, variable names are truncated to length 8

Tags: export, sas

I am exporting an SAS Data Set to an xpt file using the following code but the variable names are truncated to length 8. Is there anything I can do to keep the full names?

```
libname target xport 'C:\temp\test.xpt';
proc copy in=work out=target;
 select data;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPort files have length 8 maximum for variable names - they're intended to be highly compatible with earlier versions of SAS as well as other software, and in both cases 8 is a safe maximum.

See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/movefile/59598/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001027644.htm for more details on the limitations of the XPORT feature.

What are you trying to do with your data?  There might be a safer/easier way to get it from SAS to what you want while preserving variable names.

Comment: I am exporting the data with label to use it in R. The variable names are also capitalized. can i make it lower case? thanks.

Comment: R can import SAS data files directly.  I think the question one or two below you in fact mentions this.  If you have SAS installed, the read.ssd package can be used.  If not (or perhaps either way), try looking at this package: http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/07/really-useful-r-package-sas7bdat.html